# How to rebuild open source version of chronicle-engine

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

After spending an entire weekend trying to build the open source version of Chronicle-Engine from the "old-master" branch, I have to admit that it is very non-obvious how that can actually be done.

Is anyone in the community aware of any instructions or tips that would help? The dependancies on earlier versions of Core, Wire, Map, Queue, etc create a complicated beast that I haven't yet been able to tame.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a version available on maven central.

This is now a commercial product; however, you could use the tag chronicle-engine-2.17.1 and remove the references to the enterprise parent pom.

Depending on what you need, you may be better off using the Channels feature available in Wire, Queue or Map.

Comment: Hi Peter, I would love to be able to use 2.17.1, but it is reliant on enterprise-map classes which are not publicly available. For example, of you look at ChronicleMapKeyValueStore.java you'll see the following:

`import software.chronicle.enterprise.map.ReplicatedMap;
import software.chronicle.enterprise.map.ReplicationEventListener;
import software.chronicle.enterprise.map.cluster.MapCluster;
import software.chronicle.enterprise.map.cluster.MapClusterContext;
import software.chronicle.enterprise.map.config.MapReplicationCfg;`

Comment: After making some small modifications to to fully eliminate the dependency on enterprise-map, I'm now getting the following at runtime...any ideas? `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/openhft/chronicle/map/MapEntryOperations  at net.openhft.chronicle.engine.cfg.ChronicleMapCfg.install(ChronicleMapCfg.java:61)`